# Showing debugging error in Xamarin Live Player but not in Emulator

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-live-player

Hi I am developing an app and it is working great in Emulator or in my android device through my USB cable but when I try to run my app using Xamarin Live Player it showing debugging errors as shown in image below

[image]

Please suggest me what to do as I really want to use this feature it's time-saving!

Comment: have you figured out what is the problem?

Comment: No. I think may be because my app was developed in older version of xamarin .!